# Nested adapter views android

Tags: android, adapter

I have a couple of ListViews (one at the right side and second at the left) as a part of one child view in HorizontalListView , I want to have a following behavior :
When I update the left adapter it will reload and **only it**,

What do I do now is i call notifyDatasetCanged on the left view adapter and then notifyDarasetChanged on the parent HorisontalListView adapter which causes the refresh on **all** the children including the one to the right(if I will not notify the parent adapter nothing will happen).

What is the best way  to achieve this behavior using adapter pattern

Comment: Did you try `getListView().invalidateViews()`

Comment: May be solution, but is it the best way to do it? As I understand adapter view connection is implementation of observer design pattern, and in this case observable (in this case adapter ) should notify that it is changed and then the list view will reload it, in your solution observable should hold another interface with observer(list view) to invalidate it.